# Fixing a marginpar in (vertical) place so it does not move

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning, margins, marginpar, marginnote

I use `memoir`’s `\footnotesinmargin`, which typesets ‘footnotes’ in the margin, using `\marginpar` internally. I am very pleased with the result when combined with `marginfix`, but I have one thing I do not know how to accomplish.
While I have no problem with footnotes moving up or down the page to make a place for other footnotes, there is a special kind of `\marginpar` I want not to move: in the beginning of special sections I have relevant quotes in the margin, and I want these to stay right by the place where `\marginpar` was called.
I don’t mind footnotes moving above or below these quotes in the margin, but I do not want the quotes ever to move.

For example, in the case of the following code I want footnote 1 to move between the two quotes so it does not push the second quote.

[image: A case illustrating the problem]

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\footnotesinmargin
\usepackage{marginfix}
\setlength{\marginposadjustment}{2pt}

\newcommand{\specialquote}{\marginpar}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Capitulum primum}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\section{A very important section}

\leavevmode\specialquote{Here is a quote that looks just fine.\par\raggedleft– A. Einstein}%
\lipsum[2]

\section{Another very important section}

\leavevmode\specialquote{Alas! This quote is too high.\par\raggedleft– M. Twain}%
\lipsum[3][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[4][1-3]}
\lipsum[5][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[6][1-10]}
\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

I guess this can be done using `\marginphantom` and defining `\specialquote` as a `\marginnote`, but then one has to calculate the height of the text and I am sure there is a simpler, more elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be possible to expand the margin currently using `\vbox to \pagetotal`, copy it into a single \marginpar and delete all the previously created \marginpar boxes (which are stored in a macro delimited list).

Comment: Can you expand on this (maybe as an answer, if you wish)? Is this solution, which I must admit I do not fully understand, scalable to a long and complex document with numerous `\marginpar`s (a PhD dissertation in my case)?

Comment: The experiments with \MFX@buildmargin did not go well.  Moving on.  If the quote is too high, it means there is not enough space below the quote and you need to use \extendmargin.  If the quote is too low, the only thing you can do is lower the text you want to align with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having fiddled with this a bit, it seems the solution I proposed above is not that cumbersome to implement.
If any of you have a better solution or an improvement to this one, I would be happy to hear it

BTW, I do not understand why I have to multiply `\ht\specialquotebox` by 2, but it does work well when I do it. Any explanation?

BTW2, using the savebox (`\usebox{\specialquotebox}`) seems to add a blank line for some reason. Any solution? (Compiling the same twice is not efficient and elegant…).

[image: The output of the code]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\footnotesinmargin
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newsavebox{\specialquotebox}
\newlength{\specialquotetotalheight}

\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\specialquote}[1]{%
    \sbox{\specialquotebox}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}
            \raggedright
            #1
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \setlength{\specialquotetotalheight}{2\ht\specialquotebox + \marginparsep + 1ex}%
    \marginphantom{\specialquotetotalheight}%
    \marginnote{#1}
    % \marginnote{\usebox{\specialquotebox}}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Capitulum primum}

\lipsum[1][1-3]


\section{A very important section}

\specialquote{Here is a quote that looks just fine.\par\raggedleft– A. Einstein}%
\lipsum[2]


\section{Another very important section}

\specialquote{Hooray! This quote looks fine as well with the new method.\par\raggedleft– M. Twain}%
\lipsum[3][1]%
\footnote{\lipsum[4][1-3]}
\lipsum[3][2-6]%
\lipsum[5][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[6][1-9]}
\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well tried. However I suggest that you try your solution with using the second section text entries in your original MWE. All the footnotes appear above the Einstein quote.

Answer (score 2):

`memoir`'s `\sidepar{<text>}` puts `<text>` in the margin at the place where the macro is called, and it does not move.

I have tried but only able to come up with a partial answer. Various attempts are shown in the following MWE, which does separate the quote and footnotes.

```
% sidenotesprob.tex  SE 604614

\documentclass{memoir}

\footnotesinmargin
\sidefootmargin{right}
\sidefootmargin{left}  % seems to have no effect
%% get a reasonable result without marginfix (except that side footnotes can extend below the type area)
%\usepackage{marginfix} \setlength{\marginposadjustment}{2pt}

\newcommand{\specialquote}{\marginpar}
\renewcommand{\specialquote}{\sidepar} %% use \sidepar instead of \marginpar
\sideparmargin{right}
%\sideparmargin{left}  % puts text in left margin


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Capitulum primum}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\section{A very important section}

\leavevmode\specialquote{Here is a quote that looks just fine.\par\raggedleft– A. Einstein}%
\lipsum[2]

\section{Another very important section}

\leavevmode\specialquote{Alas! This quote is too high.\par\raggedleft– M. Twain}%
\lipsum[3][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[4][1-3]}
\lipsum[5][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[6][1-10]}
\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could try putting the quotes and footnotes in different margins. I suspect that a complete answer to your hopes would involve a radical recoding of the marginal notes, which I will not attempt; maybe someone else would.

**EDIT**

As I said above, I'm not at all sure that your problem can be resolved without major changes to LaTeX's marginal notes codes.

However I thought that perhaps you could use the `\epigraph` macro which would place your quotes in the main textblock and therefore not interfere with any marginal notes. See the `memoir` manual for the details.

```
% sidenotesprob2.tex  SE 604614

\documentclass{memoir}

\footnotesinmargin
%\sidefootmargin{right}
%\sidefootmargin{left}  % seems to have no effect
%% get a reasonable result without marginfix (except that side footnotes can extend below the type area)
\usepackage{marginfix} \setlength{\marginposadjustment}{2pt}

\newcommand{\specialquote}{\marginpar}
%\renewcommand{\specialquote}{\sidepar} %% use \sidepar instead of \marginpar
%\sideparmargin{right}
%\sideparmargin{left}  % puts text in left margin


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Capitulum primum}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\section{A very important section}

%%%% use \epigraph instead of
%\leavevmode\specialquote{Here is a quote that looks just fine.\par\raggedleft– A. Einstein}%

\epigraph{Here is a quote that looks just fine.}{A. Einstein}%


\lipsum[2]

\section{Another very important section}

%\leavevmode\specialquote{Alas! This quote is too high.\par\raggedleft– M. Twain}%

\epigraph{Alas! This quote is too high.}{M. Twain}%

\lipsum[3][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[4][1-3]}
\lipsum[5][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[6][1-10]}
\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I fear it does not solve the problem: memoir’s sidebars do not interact with `\marginpar`s, meaning that if one has a long `\marginpar` above a `\sidepar` they will overlap. With `marginfix` the problem can occur from below as well; in fact the documentation (§ 4.1) says so explicitly: ‘There are no known issues with `memoir` at present, provided that `\sidebar` is not used’. For our purpose `\sidepar` acts similarly to `\marginnote`.

Comment: @JúdaRonén As I said in my answer it did not completly solve your  problem and I suggested that a serious recoding of LaTeX's marginal notes might be required. I have extended my answer suggesting that you consider using `\epigraph` for your quotes instead of putting them in the margin to get mixed up with your other marginal entries.

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort you put into that :-). I have not tested it thoroughly yet, but I think my solution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604686/45607) does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `\tikzmark` to automatically `\extendmargin` when needed.  it takes two runs to pass the location information via the aux file.

Note: adding `\tikz[overlay]` will automatically leave vmode (like `\hbox{}`).

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\footnotesinmargin
\usepackage{marginfix}
\setlength{\marginposadjustment}{2pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{specialquote}
\renewcommand{\thespecialquote}{\roman{specialquote}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specialquote}[1]{\stepcounter{specialquote}%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\path (pic cs:SQ\thespecialquote);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xloc}{\yloc}%
    \global\let\SQoffset=\yloc}%
  \marginpar{\tikzmark{SQ\thespecialquote}#1}%
  \@ifundefined{SQ\thespecialquote}{}{\ifdim\SQoffset>2pt\relax% margin of error
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\SQoffset}{\SQoffset+\csname SQ\thespecialquote\endcsname}%
  \else
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\SQoffset\csname SQ\thespecialquote\endcsname
  \fi}%
  \ifdim\SQoffset>0pt\relax 
    \extendmargin{\SQoffset}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\xdef\expandafter\string\csname SQ\thespecialquote\endcsname{\SQoffset}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Capitulum primum}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\section{A very important section}

\specialquote{Here is a quote that looks just fine.\par\raggedleft– A. Einstein}%
\lipsum[2]

\section{Another very important section}
\specialquote{Alas! This quote is too high.\par\raggedleft– M. Twain}%
\lipsum[3][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[4][1-3]}
\lipsum[5][1-6]%
\footnote{\lipsum[6][1-10]}
\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```